# Python: Using a class as a list index

Tags: python, class

If I have a class `myclass()` which has a value variable, is there a way I can use it as an index without getting the variable, as in:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]

index = myclass(0)

data[index] = 10
```

Comment: Why? And no, indexes in lists must be positive integers, not class objects.

Comment: @Signal I agree with the "why", but you may want to look at the answer below

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: BTW indexes in lists can also be negative integers.

Comment: Shouldn't `data[index]` be `0` instead of `10`, or does `myclass` do some additional calculations when used as an index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is such a way, and logically enough, it's named `__index__`:

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, a):
...             self.a = a
...     def __index__(self):
...             return self.a
... 
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> data[foo(1)]
2
```

For usage and rationale, see [PEP0357](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0357/), which introduced `__index__`. Note that `__int__` also exists; PEP0357 explains the difference.

Comment: Thanks, that is ideal!